# Why can't I find a event for cell mouse click in grid control devexpress?

Tags: devexpress

What's the replacement event? What's the code for selecting data in grid control and put the data to textedit?

Sorry I'm a newbie..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the events of your `GridView` instance, not the events from the grid control itself.
Every grid control can have multiple Views and there is one by default (gridView1).

There are lots of other events. The one you need is **RowCellClick**.

```
private void gridView1_RowCellClick(object sender, RowCellClickEventArgs e)
{
    someTextEditControl.EditValue = e.CellValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot brow i found that event :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :) Please mark the question as solved if that answer helped you.